# iOS re-launch in background task not accomplished

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, location, magicalrecord

I'm facing an issue with location (CLVisit) when my app is killed. I've requested always location, and everything seems to work great when I test it.

I have some CoreData objects creation (with MagicalRecord) in the didVisit delegate method, that creation is working when I debug it (app is foreground or background), same when I add some local notification in the delegate and test it with app killed, but it doesn't work when I remove the notifications.

I even tried to disable automaticTermination and suddenTermination but it doesn't work.

Here is a sample of my code in didVisit function :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didVisit visit: CLVisit) {
    let activity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(options: [.suddenTerminationDisabled, .automaticTerminationDisabled], reason: "Saving location data")

    MagicalRecord.save({ (context) inUIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
        let newVisit = Visit.mr_createEntity(in: context)
        if let newVisit = newVisit {
            newVisit.accuracy = visit.horizontalAccuracy as NSNumber?
            newVisit.latitude = visit.coordinate.latitude as NSNumber?
            newVisit.longitude = visit.coordinate.longitude as NSNumber?
            newVisit.arrivalTime = visit.arrivalDate as NSDate?
            newVisit.departureTime = visit.departureDate as NSDate?
            newVisit.address = addressString
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .medium
            formatter.timeStyle = .medium
            newVisit.arrivalTimeString = formatter.string(from: newVisit.arrivalTime as! Date)
            newVisit.departureTimeString = formatter.string(from: newVisit.departureTime as! Date)
        }
    }, completion: { (bool, error) in
        ProcessInfo.processInfo.endActivity(activity)UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    })
}
```

There's a few more lines of code with if statements, but this is approximately all I do, sometimes I create 2 entries, but it works the same. When I add notifications for a debug purpose in this code everything works fine

I have some questions : can my problem be that my task in the delegate method didVisit is too long (I already reduced it to the minimum) ? Why does it works with local notifications and doesn't without them ? Do MagicalRecord works fine with and app killed and launched by a location trigger ?

Comment: How are you killing the app?

Comment: @TomHarrington  
I close it by swiping it up

Comment: I thought that was going to be relevant, but on looking at the docs I see that it should be OK. Don't know then, sorry.